# How to change the type for only one field using the openapi-generator-maven-plugin?

Tags: java, maven, date, generator, openapi

I have a schema that describes the data I get from the REST service. I can't change this scheme. There are two `date-time` type fields in the schema that have a different format:

```
"date1": {
    "type": "string",
    "description": "Date 1",
    "format": "date-time"
},
"date2": {
    "type": "string",
    "description": "Date 2",
    "format": "date-time"
}
```

```
{
    "date1": "2021-07-29T03:00:00",
    "date2": "2021-04-22T08:25:30.264Z"
}
```

By default, the open api-generator-maven-plugin creates the OffsetDateTime type for `date-time` type fields:

```
    @JsonProperty("date1")
    private OffsetDateTime date1;

    @JsonProperty("date2")
    private OffsetDateTime date2;
```

With `typeMappings` and `importMappings` I can replace OffsetDateTime to LocalDateTime:

```
<typeMappings>
    <typeMapping>OffsetDateTime=LocalDateTime</typeMapping>
</typeMappings>
<importMappings>
    <importMapping>java.time.OffsetDateTime=java.time.LocalDateTime</importMapping>
</importMappings>
```

But this replacement will happen for all fields:

```
    @JsonProperty("date1")
    private LocalDateTime date1;

    @JsonProperty("date2")
    private LocalDateTime date2;
```

Is there a way to replace OffsetDateTime with LocalDateTime for `date1` only?

That's what I want to see in the generated class:

```
    @JsonProperty("date1")
    private LocalDateTime date1;

    @JsonProperty("date2")
    private OffsetDateTime date2;
```

I understand that I can fix the generated class and replace OffsetDateTime with LocalDateTime, but I don't want to change the generated class every time after generation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From the OpenAPI docs, the date formats allowed are only a couple. If you are using a Jackson based API (like SpringMVC), what you may do (_apart from the mappings_ you have done above and have generated the code) is to register a Jackson deserializer for this class and do the conversion in that. Then, where you need `LocalDateTime` you can use `dateN.toLocalDateTime()`.

Comment: @SreeKumar, Thanks for the reply. Jackson deserializer is not exactly what I want to get. I want the `date1` field type to be LocalDateTime in the generated class, and the `date2` field type to be OffsetDateTime. I have expanded my question for more clarity.

Comment: I had got that point. Since I didn't think it possible, I merely was suggesting an alternative. I agree: what you desire, if possible, is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I eventually came to.
I am replacing OffsetDateTime with LocalDateTime using maven-replacer-plugin:

```
<replacements>
    <replacement>
        <token>import java.time.OffsetDateTime;</token>
        <value>import java.time.OffsetDateTime;\nimport java.time.LocalDateTime;</value>
    </replacement>
    <replacement>
        <token>OffsetDateTime date1</token>
        <value>LocalDateTime date1</value>
    </replacement>
</replacements>
```

Not very elegant, but it works )